# File/Path Access Error suddenly appears without folder path, name or macro being changed

Tags: excel, vba

I built a Macro for a monthly task for users in the company 6 months ago. It has worked flawlessly since, until this month, when suddenly even my local copy doesn't work anymore. We got the same error message of "File/Path Access Error".

```
Dim pm_path As String
pm_path = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("J3").Value
Workbooks.Open pm_path & "\workzone\The_Target_File.xlsx"
```

It goes like this, and cell "J3" is where user enter the path to the working folder, where a list of tasks will be performed. The code is just the beginning and it already got stuck. When I manually plug what was entered in cell "J3" and "\workzone\The_Target_File.xlsx" in my file explorer, it opens the file as it should.

Has anyone got any idea how I can troubleshoot this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the value in ```J3``` and is it on first sheet in the workbook?

Comment: Always helps to `Debug.Print pm_path` to see if it is exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Did you add another (hidden?) sheet as the first sheet in the workbook?